# Retrofit java.lang.illegalStateException:Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 591

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I am hitting an api with put request and pass Multipart data. Here is my interface:

```
@Multipart
    @PUT("profile")
    Call<ProfileSetupResponse> vendorProfile1(
            @Header("access-token") String token,
            @Part("businessName") RequestBody businessName,
            @Part("step") RequestBody step,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part image,
            @Query("categories[]") List<String> categories,
            @Part("country") RequestBody country,
            @Part("contact") RequestBody contact,
            @Part("aboutUs") RequestBody aboutUs,
            @Part("businessDetail") RequestBody businessDetail,
            @Part("businessEmail") RequestBody businessEmail,
            @Query("tags[]") List<String> tags
    );
```

I am getting the **"java.lang.illegalStateException:Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 591"** exception in the response from server.

Here is my method to pass data to server:

```
Call<ProfileSetupResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().vendorProfile1("Token",
                    bName, bStep, filePart, categories, bCountry, bContact, bAboutUs, bDetail, bEmail, tags);
```

Here Categories and Tags are ArrayList<>.

I am new to working with Retrofit please someone help.

Update to Question:

```
 RequestBody bName = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "businessName");
            RequestBody bCountry = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "businessCountry");
            RequestBody bAboutUs = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "businessAboutUs");
            RequestBody bDetail = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "businessDetail");
            RequestBody bEmail = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "businessEmail");
            RequestBody bContact = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "businessContact");
            RequestBody bStep = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "1");
```

I am not sending arraylists or image just to check the response, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Try changing `categories[]` to `categories` and `tags[]` to `tags`

Comment: @DanishAnsari No effect

Comment: This log is very limited. Can you provided more detailed logs? Update it in the question

Comment: @DanishAnsari Check the code now

Comment: Update logs. Check in your Logcat (Alt + 6 in Android Studio)  when app crashes.

Comment: @DanishAnsari The app is not crashing, I just get the response from Retrofit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217310/discussion-between-hasnain-ghias-and-danish-ansari).